# Cannot access if exists select variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble finding the correct syntax to make this work?

I have a table with the columns id and color and I want to print out all of the id's for a specific color.

```
if exists(select id from mytable where color = 'red')
    print id


if exists(select id from mytable where color = 'red')
    print SCOPE_IDENTITY() --which won't work because i'm using select rather than insert
```

Comment: Why are you using `PRINT` from SQL?  SQL isn't designed to easily "print" the results of a query.

Comment: It's just a contrived example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PRINT` only prints one value. It looks like you want to loop through the results and print each value, which will require a cursor:

```
DECLARE @id INT
DECLARE id_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT id from mytable where color = 'red'

OPEN id_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM id_cursor 
INTO @id

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @id

    FETCH NEXT FROM id_cursor 
    INTO @id
END 
CLOSE id_cursor;
DEALLOCATE id_cursor;
```

Which seems ridiculous to do in SQL and is why I said in my comment that SQL is not designed to easily print the results of a query - you may be better off returning a result set and letting the *consumer* print the results.

Comment: Ok thats what I was looking for sorry about the confusion I tried to simplify my example and I think I made it to simple but the cursor is exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

id isnt defined.

The id in the exists subquery doesnt exist outside that subquery.

You could do this:

```
declare @id int;
select @id = id from table_name;
if (@id is not null) 
    print @id;
```

Comment: Sorry my example wasn't quite right for what I was trying to do, I have just updated it :-)

Comment: @jamesla. You still have the problem in your code. ID is a column name, not a variable. You have to declare a variable like John did.

Comment: This only prints 1 id rather than all of the id's with the specified color. (not your fault I realised I had omitted this and updated the question after you posted this John).

Answer (score 0):

You just need `select id from mytable where color = 'red`

This will return every id where color is red. If there aren't any, then you will get a single row in the dataset with  in  the id column

Comment: Last sentence isn't correct. If there aren't any, then they will get an empty resultset.

Comment: This is technically correct however my example is contrived for the reason that I need to run additional queries using the id, so we need to stick to using print.